# Jmeter + JSF can't pass login filter

Tags: jsf, testing, authentication, jmeter

I got a problem when use Jmeter to test a JSF application.
I'm a newbie in Jmeter, follow some post on net i did 
[image]
And code filter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    try {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);

        if (!httpRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpRequest.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        String strRequestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        // httpRequest.getServletPath()
        // httpRequest.getServerName()
        if (strRequestURI.indexOf("/public/") >= 0)
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        else if ( (strRequestURI.indexOf("/login.xhtml") >= 0)
                || strRequestURI.contains("javax.faces.resource")
                || (strRequestURI.indexOf("/admin-access-denied.xhtml") >= 0)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else if ((httpSession != null) && (httpSession.getAttribute(SessionBean.SESSION_KEY) != null)) {
            if (strRequestURI.indexOf("/lazy-load.xhtml") >= 0) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I did all things that i read : add Coockie Manager, add Regular Expression Extrator, add parameter to Http request but after run test, my response data is blank ( only access to login.xhtml page )
[image]

But response is blank , only login page is showed .

Pls help me to solve this problem. 
PS: I run debug mode and httpSession.getAttribute(SessionBean.SESSION_KEY) is always null , its set on login controller ( when login successed ).

```
HttpSession session = SessionBean.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(SessionBean.SESSION_KEY, sessionData);
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

1. Most likely your `javax.faces.Viewstate` value is not propertly correlated, you're sending `${viewstate}` instead of the extracted value, most likely your [Regular Expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) fails somewhere

   [image: Regular Expression Extractor]
2. It's better to put PostProcessors as children of the specific Samplers, otherwise they are being triggered on each sampler causing execution overhead and in some cases [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) data loss

   So your test should have the following structure:

   - lazy-load.xhtml

     - Extract Viewstate
   - login.xhtml
3. You may want to consider using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) instead of Regular Expressions Extractor as Regular Expressions are fragile, sensitive to markup change and complex ones can hardly be understood and maintained.

   Example expressions:

   - XPath: `//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState]/@value`
   - CSS: 
          - Expression: `input[id=javax.faces.ViewState]`
          - Attribute: `value`